# Candidate function not viable: passing std::function as a parameter (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I am trying to use std::function to pass as a parameter to another function but keep receiving the following error:

```
cannot resolve overloaded function 'returnValidsForHuman' based on conversion to type 'std::function<std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >(City<20, 20>&, std::pair<int, int>)>'
   64 |         coordinate_pairs valid_coordinates = findValidCoordinate(grid, organism.getPosition(), returnValidsForHuman);
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include "../inc/City.h++"
#include "../inc/Organism.h++"
#include "../inc/Zombie.h++"
#include "../inc/Human.h++"

using std::cout, std::endl;

typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> coordinate_pairs;
typedef std::pair<int, int> coordinate;

/** below are the methods used for actual functionality of the application */
template<typename T>
void updateGrid(T& grid, Organism& organism);

/** finds the valid coordinates an organism can move to */
template<typename T>
coordinate_pairs findValidCoordinate(T& grid, coordinate pos, std::function<coordinate_pairs(T&, coordinate)> _func);

/** returns the valid coordinates for Zombie */
template<typename T>
coordinate_pairs returnValidsForZombie(T& grid, coordinate coord);

/** returns the valid coordinates for Human */
template<typename T>
coordinate_pairs returnValidsForHuman(T& grid, coordinate coord);

int main() {
    /** main loop of the program */

    City grid = City<20, 20>();
    Zombie z1 = Zombie();

    updateGrid(grid, z1);

    return 0;
};

/** implementations */

template<typename T>
void updateGrid(T& grid, Organism& organism) {
    if(organism.toString() == "H") {
        coordinate_pairs valid_coordinates = findValidCoordinate(grid, organism.getPosition(), returnValidsForHuman);
    } else if(organism.toString() == "Z") {
        coordinate_pairs valid_coordinates = findValidCoordinate(grid, organism.getPosition(), returnValidsForZombie);
    }
};

/** find valid coordinates surrounding the organism */
template<typename T>
coordinate_pairs findValidCoordinate(T& grid, coordinate pos, std::function<coordinate_pairs(T&, coordinate)> _func) {
    return _func(grid, pos);
};

/** returns the valid coordinates for Zombie */
template<typename T>
coordinate_pairs returnValidsForZombie(T& grid, coordinate coord) {
    coordinate_pairs valids = coordinate_pairs();
};

/** returns the valid coordinates for Human */
template<typename T>
coordinate_pairs returnValidsForHuman(T& grid, coordinate coord) {

};
```

I'm not too sure what the problem may be and was wondering if someone would be able to see what the problem may be?

Background: I am implementing a function for both zombie and human classes and I wanted to pass those functions to the `findValidCoordinate` function to find the valid coordinates in a 2D grid (City).

Comment: Strong style suggestion: `typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> coordinate_pairs;` => `using coordinate_pairs = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>;`

Comment: Also, put the second typedef first:  `using coordinate = std::pair<int, int>;` and then `using coordinate_pairs = std::vector<coordinate>;`

Comment: Also, your functions don't need trailing semicolons.

Comment: Note that `returnValidsForHuman` promises to return a `coordinate_pairs` value but returns nothing. Are you sure this isn't your problem?

Comment: There could be less code than this to demonstrate the problem, see [mre]

Comment: That didnt seem to fix the issue, its saying that ``updateGrid`` template function is not viable as theres no overload for either of the ``returnValidsFor..`` functions matching ``'std::function<coordinate_pairs(City<20, 20>&, coordinate)>``; not really sure what this means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass a function template `returnValidsForHuman` (resp. `returnValidsForZombie`) as the `std::function` argument. Here is a more minimal example of your problem:

```cpp
#include <utility> //for std::pair
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using coordinate = std::pair<int, int>;
using coordinate_pairs = std::vector<coordinate>;

template<typename T>
coordinate_pairs returnValidsForHuman(T& grid, coordinate coord);

template<typename T>
coordinate_pairs findValidCoordinate(T& grid, coordinate coord, std::function<coordinate_pairs(T&, coordinate)> _func);

struct City {};

int main()
{
    City grid;
    auto pos = coordinate{0, 0};
    coordinate_pairs valid_coordinates = findValidCoordinate(grid, pos, returnValidsForHuman); // OFFENDING LINE
}
```

Compiler error with gcc 12.2:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:20:61: error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'returnValidsForHuman' based on conversion to type 'std::function<std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >(City&, std::pair<int, int>)>'
   20 |     coordinate_pairs valid_coordinates = findValidCoordinate(grid, pos, returnValidsForHuman);
      |
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nsPeTxE65

---

To solve your problem, you need to change the last line of the main function *(marked with `// OFFENDING LINE`)* to

```cpp
coordinate_pairs valid_coordinates = findValidCoordinate(grid, pos, returnValidsForHuman<City>);
```

This way you pass a proper function template instantiation with the correct signature.

https://godbolt.org/z/Pr4fM44hP

---

As a side note, you don't have to use `std::function` here. `std::function` uses runtime polymorphism and type-erasure so that you can store different functions of the same signature in a contiguous container. This is not needed and it introduces a non-negligable runtime overhead. Instead, you could use another template parameter for your function, e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename F>
coordinate_pairs findValidCoordinate(T& grid, coordinate coord, F&& _func);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jh7nnaMTT